# How to create schema to generate a JSON Array using Schema and transformers provided by DataFaker API in Java?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, faker

I am using [DataFaker](https://github.com/datafaker-net/datafaker) library to create schema for JSON Object and Array. Since the use of [Format](https://www.datafaker.net/documentation/formats/) is deprecated, I am trying with [Transformation Schemas](https://www.datafaker.net/documentation/schemas/). I tried examples given under the Format section of official documentation to create a schema for Json Array but wasn't successful.
Example JSON Array -

[
{
"firstName": "Oleta",
"lastName": "Toy"
},
{
"firstName": "Gerard",
"lastName": "Windler"
}
]

Answer (score 0):

Raised the same question on Datafaker GitHub and got the solution.

JsonTransformer transformer = JsonTransformer.builder().formattedAs(JSON_ARRAY).build();

Adding the direct link here.
https://github.com/datafaker-net/datafaker/issues/720#issuecomment-1445929651